# How to remove all key bindings from tmux session?

Tags: bash, tmux

I am building a GUI that uses tmux and I want to ensure that all existing bindings are removed when the program is started.

I tried using:

```bash
$ tmux unbind-key -a
```

since the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux) states:

> If -a is present, all key bindings are removed.

however this does not seem to work, since if I list the binds again with `list-keys` I still see all of them

Answer (score 0):

By default it uses the default table (`-T prefix`). To unbind all keys in all tables:

```bash
for table in prefix root copy-mode copy-mode-vi; do
    tmux unbind -a -T "$table"
done
```